# Problem with HereMaps Android Premium latest SDK

Tags: android, react-native, here-api

When included latest HEREMap's android SDK `HERE_Android_SDK_Premium_v3.10.1_96`. 
I am getting following error while building.

**`com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'`**

Its working fine when `HERE_Android_SDK_Starter_v3.10.0_20` sdk is used.

Am trying this in a **react-native project** by simply including the HERE-SDK.aar file in a new react native app also, the same error is coming.

I could solve the compilation error by deleting libgnustl_shared.so from .aar file. But then the map is not displayed, instead a screen is loaded in blue color.

Any idea why this might be happening?

**[Edit]**
I could see below error when libgnustl_shared.so was deleted :-/.

`E/HereMapView: Error initializing map: Unknown error occurred during engine init.`

Comment: Hi, would you show me the code how did you implement HereMap Premium SDK in React native android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by updating my `app/build.gradle`. Following code was added in the gradle,

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libgnustl_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
}
```